# Creating the SQL which will make running-total fields in a new table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query which should create three running total fields, based on the TimesheetEntryID foreign key.

I would like to create a temporary table with a running total for every value of TimesheetEntryID. However when I run my query, Access asks for a specific value for [Hours Accumulation Temporary].TimesheetEntryID. I would like instead Access to do the query for EVERY TimesheetEntryID. Such that for every TimesheetEntryID, three running total fields are generated.

I don't understand why my query makes Access want a singular value for [Hours Accumulation Temporary].TimesheetEntryID

[image: My Query]

Comment: Because [Hours Accumulation Temporary] table is not included in the FROM clause. When Access cannot find an object referenced in WHERE clause, it treats it as a popup input prompt.

Comment: How are you using `[Hours Accumulation Temporary]` before you've created it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running correlated subqueries, use aliases to differentiate the same named sources between outer query and subquery. Currently you are attempting to use the *very* table you intend to create inside your query when actually you want to point to the outer query field: `[Daily Timesheet].TimesheetEntryID`.

Consequently, simply adjust query with appropriate aliases. Below shows all subqueries are referenced with *sub* joined to corresponding letter in outer query. Additionally, an added condition is included to match on same *EmployeeID*:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeName, d.TimesheetEntryID, 
       (SELECT SUM(sub_d.VacationHoursUsed - sub_d.VacationHours)
        FROM [Daily Timesheet] sub_d
        WHERE sub_d.TimesheetEntryID <= d.TimesheetEntryID
          AND sub_d.EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID) AS VacationHoursAvailable,

       (SELECT SUM(sub_d.BankedHoursUsed - sub_d.BankedHours)
        FROM [Daily Timesheet] sub_d
        WHERE sub_d.TimesheetEntryID <= d.TimesheetEntryID
          AND sub_d.EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID) AS BankedHoursAvailable,

       (SELECT SUM(sub_d.PersonalHoursUsed - sub_d.PersonalHours)
        FROM [Daily Timesheet] sub_d
        WHERE sub_d.TimesheetEntryID <= d.TimesheetEntryID
          AND sub_d.EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID) AS PersonalHoursAvailable

INTO [Hours Accumulation Temporary]

FROM [Employee Master] e 
INNER JOIN [Daily Timesheet] d ON e.EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID

ORDER BY e.EmployeeID, d.TimesheetEntryID
```

Comment: That works perfectly! I much better understand which table or sub table I am actually referencing now, thank you so much

Comment: Great to hear. Glad I could help. Happy coding!